# Calculating reciprocal of last row in dataframe and including it as a 'new' last row in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
DF: A B C D E F G H 
 0  J S T 1 2 3 4 5 
 1  R A M 2 3 4 5 6 
sum 0 0 0 3 5 7 9 11
```

and I would like to add a new row to DF, that the dataframe takes the last tiw of the dataframe (in this case 'sum') and gets the reciprocal

So it should read as 
DF:

```
A B C D E F G H 
 0  J S T 1 2 3 4 5 
 1  R A M 2 3 4 5 6 
sum 0 0 0 3 5 7 9 11 
rec 0 0 0 0.3 .25 etc etc
```

Comment: Where are you getting these reciprocal values from? `0.25` seems wrong

Comment: `df.loc['rec',:]=1/df.loc['sum'].astype(int)
`

Comment: Sorry, that should have been 0.2. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
df = df.append(df.loc['sum', 'D':'H'].apply(lambda x: 1 / x)\
    .rename('rec')).fillna(0)
```